# Contar el número total de archivos y archivos en subcarpetas de un directorio en PHP (Framework Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

Intento obtener el número total de subcarpetas y archivos totales dentro de subdirectorios de una carpeta en especifico (Simular el "propiedades con un click derecho de windows, que devuelva la cantidad de archivos y archivos en subcarpetas).

He intentado con el

```
$count = scandir($directorio); 
//Solo devuelve el numero de archivos del directorio exceptuando archivos dentro de subdirectorios
```

Y también con

```
$count= count(glob($directorio ,GLOB_BRACE)); 
//He intentado también con un count pero sin éxito logro obtener el numero total.
```

Espero puedan solucionar mi problema, me basta con tener sólo el número total y no identificar su contenido.

Anexo mi función donde debería estar el código

```
public function filesCloud(){
        //Se crea un array como respuesta para ajax
                    $response=[];
                    $files=[];
        //Directorio cuyo contenido contiene archivos, subcarpetas con archivos.
                    $directorio =  public_path('beautree/pointclouds/'); 
        //Aquí debe ir el contador de archivos, archivos dentro de subcarpetas del directorio
                    $count = scandir($directorio);
                    array_push($files, $count); //Se anexa al array

                    $response=[
                        'files'=>$files
                    ];
        //Retorna respuesta para ajax.
                    return response()->json($response);
                }
```

Comment: Prueba con `Storage::allFiles('/algun-directorio')` y `Storage::allDirectories('/algun-directorio');` https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#directories

Comment: Lo he intentando como mencionas pero no me devuelve el tamaño del array (Cantidad de archivos totales)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el archivo `/config/filesystems.php`, crea un disco que apunte al directorio `/public` bajo el índice `'disks'` para tener acceso a ese directorio con la facade `Storage`:

```
'disks' => [
    // tus otros discos aquí, agrega el siguiente

    'public_dir' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path(),
    ],
],
```

Luego en tu función `filesCloud()` puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
// especifica el subdirectorio al que quieres acceder dentro de /public
$directorio =  '/beautree/pointclouds';

// obtén los arrays de archivos y directorios que estén ubicados ahí
$directorios_array = Storage::disk('public_dir')->allDirectories($directorio);
$archivos_array = Storage::disk('public_dir')->allFiles($directorio);

// luego puedes usar la función count() de php para contar todos los elementos del array
$response = [
    'directorios' => count($directorios_array) ,
    'archivos' => count($archivos_array)
];

return response()->json($response);
```

Comment: TOTALMENTE FUNCIONAL, muchisimas gracias amigo, ahora puedo no solo devolver el número total de archivos si no de recuperar exactamente cuantos directorios y/o archivos hay. Se agradece.